# LinkedIn API update campaign group end date

Tags: linkedin-api

How can I update the campaign group only end date?

Seems this is possible via LinkedIn Campaign Manager, but using API https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCampaignGroupsV2 it returns:

```
/CampaignGroup/runSchedule/start is required but missing
```

in case I set start as it was, or as now, it returns an error:

```
/CampaignGroup/runSchedule/start cannot be updated unless in draft state.
```

Comment: the problem is solved if I set original start date